how to access elements inside svg object with selenium
I am trying to access speed data from OpenStreetBrowser with Selenium but I am unable to access SVG elements of the website.
This is what I've tried so far
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.openstreetbrowser.org')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

xpath_expression = f"//a[contains(text(), 'Transportation')]"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_expression))).click()

xpath_expression = f"//a[contains(text(), 'Individual Traffic')]"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_expression))).click()

xpath_expression = f"//a[contains(text(), 'Maxspeed')]"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_expression))).click()

xpath_expression = f"//li[contains(text(), 'search')]"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='tabs-list']//li[@title='search']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tabs-section nominatim-search selected']//input"))).send_keys('53.40125254855821,-3.0876670857133757')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tabs-section nominatim-search selected']//ul//li"))).click()

a = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='map']//div[1]//div[2]//svg")))

I am getting the following exception
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF737801502+60802]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF73777AC02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737637CE4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737686D4D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737686E1C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7376CCE37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7376AABBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7376CA224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7376AA923]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737678FEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737679C21]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF737B0411D+3217821]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF737B460B7+3488055]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF737B3F03F+3459263]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7378BB846+823494]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737785F9F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737780EC4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF737781052]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7377718A4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF87E237344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF87FD826B1+33]

It seems like each road stretch was arranged as an image/tile. I want to click on each image and then Details option on the popup to gather the required data. How can I access each tile on this website and click on it?
Thanks in advance!

SVG elements have to be treated differently than other elements. You need to update your locator slightly to get access to them. Instead of
(By.XPATH, "//svg")

you need to use
(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']")

So your SVG locator would be changed to
a = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='map']//div[1]//div[2]//*[name()='svg']")))


its working but my objective is to click on each line (svg element if i am not wrong). i am able to acess svg and path tags as well but am unable to click on any line. once i click a pop up will appear and i can gather data from popup div
